# KnockoutJS checkboxlist not binding selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a checkbox list with the following values:

```
"AllAuctionTypes": [
{
  "AuctionTypeID": "e42fde21-807c-4c81-938d-1918ca13f28b",
  "AuctionTypeName": "Truck & Trailer",
  "AuctionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
},
{
  "AuctionTypeID": "eb1cc1c2-d08d-45b6-8c46-1dbd9d54bd35",
  "AuctionTypeName": "Agriculture",
  "AuctionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
},
{
  "AuctionTypeID": "edb81092-0bfc-462e-a50e-4510feb54c55",
  "AuctionTypeName": "Plant & Machinery",
  "AuctionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
]
```

I want to **data-bind** the **checked** value from data that I obtain from my server. Which looks like this:

```
  {
  "AuctionID": "88848ed7-c2bd-4428-9c4c-c524f2717051",
  "AuctionName": "Another Auction",
  "AuctionDate": "2015-04-22",
  "AuctionTime": "16:50:00",
  "AuctionLocation": "LolVille",
  "AuctionContactPerson": "Bill",
  "AuctionContactNumber": "0115552222",
  "AuctionEMail": "bill@auctionman.co.za",
  "AuctionWebsite": "http://somesite.co.za",
  "AuctionType": [
    {
      "AuctionTypeID": "e42fde21-807c-4c81-938d-1918ca13f28b",
      "AuctionTypeName": "Truck & Trailer",
      "AuctionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    },
    {
      "AuctionTypeID": "edb81092-0bfc-462e-a50e-4510feb54c55",
      "AuctionTypeName": "Plant & Machinery",
      "AuctionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

The **AuctionType** value(s) are the items that should be marked as selected, but it does not seem to do the binding. Here is my HTML with the bindings:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label>Auction Catagory</label>
                                <div>
                                    <table data-bind="foreach: AllAuctionTypes">
                                        <tr>
                                            @*Debugging*@
                                            <td data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($parent.Auction.AuctionType)"></td>
                                            <td>

                                                @*this is the segment I am trying to bind*@
                                                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.Auction.AuctionType" />  <span data-bind="text: AuctionTypeName"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

But it doesn't seem to bind the values based on what was selected, or I am just binding it incorrectly.

Here is a screen cap of the screen showing the debugging segment and the unchecked boxes
[image: Screen Capture]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried binding a boolean value to the `checked` binding? I see in the knockout docs that the `checked` binding behaves loosely when applied to checkboxes and bound to non-boolean values.

Comment: @CameronTinker No not yet. but also not sure how I would go about doing that

Comment: I'm confused. When should the box be checked/unchecked? When the data is present/undefined?

Comment: @Tyrsius When the data is present, in Auction the Box should be checked

Comment: @JacquesBronkhorst Is unchecking the checkbox intended to delete the data?

Comment: @Tyrsius Yes. I am building an Update panel for the Information provided. And the AuctionType should be able to change at any time

Comment: That is not really how the `checked` binding works. This could be easily achieved with a custom binding, or problematically achieved with some awkward viewmodel subscriptions or writeable computeds. Would you accept a custom binding for this? On a seperate note, unchecking a box that causes the entire row to disappear is an unexpected and possible strange user experience. I think a simple "delete" button would be better.

Comment: @Tyrsius Im busy trying to build one as we speak :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working with a custom Checked binding as suggested by [Tyrsius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788260/tyrsius).

The Checkbox binding looks like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.IsChecked(AuctionTypeID), checkedValue: $data" /> <span data-bind="text: AuctionTypeName"></span>
```

I provide the IsChecked function with the AuctionTypeID and it runs a comparison to see which ID has been checked.

Here is the IsChecked function that works perfectly for me:

```
 self.IsChecked = function (ListID) {
        var K;
        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Auction.AuctionType(), function (item) {
            return ListID === item.AuctionTypeID
        });

        if (!match) {
            K = false;
        } else {
            K = true;
        }
        return K;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some odd scoping to deal with, but this works:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label>Auction Category</label>
                                <div>
                                    <table data-bind="foreach: allAuctionTypes">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: AuctionTypeID, checked: $root.auctionTypeSelected($data)" />  <span data-bind="text: AuctionTypeName"></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
```

JS:

```
var auction = {
  "AuctionID": "88848ed7-c2bd-4428-9c4c-c524f2717051",
  "AuctionName": "Another Auction",
  "AuctionDate": "2015-04-22",
  "AuctionTime": "16:50:00",
  "AuctionLocation": "LolVille",
  "AuctionContactPerson": "Bill",
  "AuctionContactNumber": "0115552222",
  "AuctionEMail": "bill@auctionman.co.za",
  "AuctionWebsite": "http://somesite.co.za",
  "AuctionType": [
    {
      "AuctionTypeID": "e42fde21-807c-4c81-938d-1918ca13f28b",
      "AuctionTypeName": "Truck & Trailer",
      "AuctionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    },
    {
      "AuctionTypeID": "edb81092-0bfc-462e-a50e-4510feb54c55",
      "AuctionTypeName": "Plant & Machinery",
      "AuctionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }
  ]
};
var allAuctionTypes = [
{
  "AuctionTypeID": "e42fde21-807c-4c81-938d-1918ca13f28b",
  "AuctionTypeName": "Truck & Trailer",
  "AuctionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
},
{
  "AuctionTypeID": "eb1cc1c2-d08d-45b6-8c46-1dbd9d54bd35",
  "AuctionTypeName": "Agriculture",
  "AuctionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
},
{
  "AuctionTypeID": "edb81092-0bfc-462e-a50e-4510feb54c55",
  "AuctionTypeName": "Plant & Machinery",
  "AuctionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
];

var vm = function(auctionTypes, auction){
    var self = this;
    self.allAuctionTypes = ko.observableArray(auctionTypes);
    self.auction = ko.observable(auction);
    self.auctionTypeSelected = function(auctionType) {
        var selected = false;
        $.each(self.auction().AuctionType, function(i, aType){
            if (auctionType.AuctionTypeID === aType.AuctionTypeID) {
                selected = true;
                return; // break from for loop
            }
        });
        return selected;
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm(allAuctionTypes, auction));
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/ccjjc44d/